# Is there any way to call SceneDelegate methods in iOS 14 app life cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

We know Apple has drastically simplified the SwiftUI app life cycle (WWDC20). I have seen the video of Mr.Paul Hudson about the new changes in SwiftUI in which he has explained how to access AppDelegate methods in "@main or :App" struct.

I want to know if there is any way to access the SceneDelegate methods?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no access for `SceneDelegate` now in SwiftUI 2.0 life-cycle. Some of callbacks you can use with `.onChange` for *[.active, .inactive, .background]* states as shown [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567952/12299030)

or... there is nothing wrong in continue using UIKit life-cycle

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you @Asperi for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It's is an example to access life cycle in AppDelegate.

```
struct PodcastScene: Scene {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                LibraryView()
                DiscoverView()
                SearchView()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: phase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .active:
                // App became active
            case .inactive:
                // App became inactive
            case .background:
                // App is running in the background
            @unknown default:
                // Fallback for future cases
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you add a framework configuration like Firebase, you can override the init and input your code here.

```
struct PodcastScene: Scene {

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                LibraryView()
                DiscoverView()
                SearchView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```