# When to use SwiftUI Interface with UIKit Life Cycle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I like to know why we should create and use a SwiftUI Interface with UIKit Life Cycle?
I get confused about it! Because:

1-if you want UIKit programming then go and choose Storyboard for Interface and then choose UIKit for Life Cycle.

2-if you want SwiftUI programming then go and choose SwiftUI for Interface and then choose SwiftUI for Life Cycle.

3-if you want change your Swift Language then go change it to Objective-C and you will get Storyboard as Interface and UIKit as Life Cycle.

Here comes Option 4:

4- You can have SwiftUI for Interface and UIKit as life Cycle! which is the Topic of this Question!
If I am not wrong SwiftUI handle things different than UIKit, we do not need define delegate or protocols in SwiftUI or things like that, but why we get **AppDelegate** and **SceneDelegate** in this case! what is pros and cons in case we create such a Xcode project?

Comment: When you have deployment target iOS 13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With SwiftUI you should in most cases use SwiftUI lifecycle.

If you need some AppDelegate methods you can use `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`:

- [SwiftUI app life cycle iOS14 where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62538110/8697793)

There are some cases, however, when you need UIKit lifecycle:

- access to `SceneDelegate` (see [Is there any way to call SceneDelegate methods in iOS 14 app life cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62696513/8697793))
- deployment target iOS 13 (SwiftUI lifecycle is available on iOS 14+).