# How do you migrate to the new SwiftUI App Protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app that still has the Scene / App Delegate files and would like to migrate it to the new SwiftUI App Protocol.

Is this only a matter of deleting the Scene / App Delegate files, then adding my ContentView (Initial View in my case) to the @main struct???

Thank you!

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to follow these steps to migrate a SwiftUI application to the new `App` life cycle:

1. Create a new `App` struct and add the `@main` annotation:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

2. Remove the `@main` annotation from `AppDelegate`.
3. Remove `Scene Configuration` from `Info.plist`:

[image]

4. (Optionally) Move `AppDelegate`/`SceneDelegate` methods:

- [SwiftUI app life cycle iOS14 where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62538110/8697793)
- [Is there any way to call SceneDelegate methods in iOS 14 app life cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62696513/8697793)

5. Now you can remove the `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate` classes from the project (first make sure the app is indeed working as expected).
6. Reinstall the app (as suggested in the comments).

Comment: Also you need totally reinstall app from your device with clean up

Comment: You actually don't need to reinstall the app, at least on the simulator. You just need to completely close the app and restart

Comment: @SoundBlaster you are such a life-saver. I was having a heart attack not understanding why after doing all of this, my app would launch as Catalyst target but not load the SwiftUI 'App' on iOS.

Comment: @GBreen12 not sure about that. I just followed the steps exactly and was only getting a black screen on iOS until I removed and reinstalled the app.