# Set UISceneConfiguration outside configurationForConnecting function

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have migrated my [App to the SwiftUI App protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66093835/how-do-you-migrate-to-the-new-swiftui-app-protocol/66094397#66094397).

I also want [to use AppDelegate ans SceneDelegate](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/app-delegate-scene-delegate-swiftui/) by adding this code in appdelegate:

```
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
    options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
  ) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    let sceneConfig = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    sceneConfig.delegateClass = FSSceneDelegate.self // 
    return sceneConfig
  }
```

The problem is that if I update my app, this function is not called. I have to uninstall the app and reinstall it to get this function called.

Is there another way to set the `UISceneConfiguration` outside this function ?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the info.plist scene manifest part, except for `enable multiple windows`.